# how to add playwright docker image to docker compose?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, playwright

I am building Django app where I want to run Django and playwright images in 1 container in Docker Desktop (locally).

Below you can see my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./docker_playwright_test
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./docker_playwright_test/:/usr/src/docker_playwright_test/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Django is running fine on my localhost but I am not sure how to add [Playwright image](https://playwright.dev/docs/docker) to docker-compose file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: make sure you're in Linux Container in Docker.

Step 2: Go to `C:\Users\[User Name]\.docker\config.json`
Replace credsStore to credStore

Step 3: create Dockerfile, .dockerignore and docker-compose.yml file

Step 4: docker-compose format.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
  backend:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Docker123!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1440:1433"
```

try to use sam ports as I mentioned here.
`User = sa`, `Database = master`
It will run perfectly fine. IA.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the Dockerfile within the service and build key (with configuration options applied at build time), like this:

```
web:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

then, you can specify the Docker image in the specified Dockerfile, like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic
WORKDIR /docker_playwright_test
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
```

Otherwise, you can specify the Docker image in the docker-compose file in the service section:

```
web:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic
  volumes:
    - ./docker_playwright_test/:/usr/src/docker_playwright_test/
  ports:
    - 8000:8000
```